# Within a Kubernetes cluster catch outgoing requests from a Pod and redirect to a different target

Tags: kubernetes, proxy, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster with 3 nodes. In each node i have a frontend application running in a Pod and backend application running in a separate Pod.
I send data from the frontend application to the backend application, to do this i utilise the Cluster IP Service and k8 dns resource. 
I also have a function in my frontend where i send data to a separate service unrelated to my k8s cluster. I send this data using a standard AJAX request to a url with a payload  i.e http://my-seperate-service-unrelated-tok8.com.
All of this works correctly and the cluster operates as i want. - i have this cluster deployed to GKE.   I now want to run this cluster local using minikube, which i have been able to do, however, when i am running locally i do not want to send data to my external service - instead i want to forward it to either a new Pod i will create or just not send it.

The problem here is i need a proxy to intercept outgoing network traffic, check if the outgoing request is the request i am looking for and if it is then redirect it.

I understand each node running in a cluster has a kube-proxy service running within the node - which is used to forward traffic to the relevant services in the cluster.   I would like to either extend this service, or create a new proxy service where i can listen for outgoing traffic to a specific url and redirect it.   Is this possible to do in a k8 cluster? I assume there is a Service i can create to listen for all outgoing requests and redirect specific requests based on rules i set.

I wasn’t sure if k8 clusters have a Service already configured i can simply add to - that’s why i thought of the kube-proxy, would anyone be able to advice on this?  I wanted to add this proxy so i don’t have to change my code when its ran locally in minikube or deployed to GKE.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you make the frontend configurable and decide there where to point the ajax requests to?

Comment: In principle you can do this with Istio too, but I agree with @Thomas: doing this with explicit configuration (like getting the URL into an environment variable from a ConfigMap) is better.

Comment: You could easily achieve this with istio rules, but that would be an overkill if you want to do this just for your local test cluster. Rather the configmap options seems best for this use case.

Comment: Thank you fr your advice. I am still confused on one part i was hoping you could advice me on. To use config maps i have had to create 2 separate files. One i apply when running locally and another i apply when running on GKE. Is there a way to have a single file and kubernetes takes care of what values to use in what environment? As in can kubernetes tell i am running in the Minikube environment so use the associated values in the config map and then the same when deployed to GKE? Is there a way to know what environment you are running in to apply values conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

I did a tool that help you to forward a service to another service,local port, service from other cluster, etc...

This way you can have exactly your same urls, ports and code... but the underlying services gets "replaced", if I understand correctly this is what you are looking for.

Here is a quick example of an stage service being replaced with my local 3000 port
[image: link service]

This is the repository with more info and examples: [linker-tool](https://github.com/vicjicaman/linker-tool)

If you are interested let me know if you need help or have any question.